# Passing a $rootScope value in a javascript that is placed within a view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angulartics

So as the question title says, I have an object in my $rootScope (let's call it $rootScope.appConfiguration), which takes a value in the .run of my module:

```
angular.module('myapp',[...])
.provider('appConfigurationProvider',function(){...})
.constant(...)
.run(function($rootScope) {
$rootScope.appConfiguration = appConfiguration;
});
```

(The ... parts are just skipped code, to make things more readable)

Then my in my index.html I am implementing [angulartics-piwik](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics-piwik):

```
<body ng-app>

<!-- Piwik -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var _paq = _paq || [];
//_paq.push(['trackPageView']);
_paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
(function() {
    var u = appConfiguration.PiwikUrl;
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u + 'piwik.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', appConfiguration.PiwikSiteId]);
    var d = document, g = d.createElement('script'), s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type = 'text/javascript';
    g.async = true;
    g.defer = true;
    g.src = u + 'piwik.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
})();
</script>
<!-- End Piwik Code -->
...
```

As you can see I want to use 2 values from my appConfiguration object, PiwikUrl and PiwikSiteId but I have no idea how to "pass" the object in the javascript. Obviously as the code is now I'm getting an "appConfiguration is not defined" error message..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a different approach, using a service and a configuration constant (you can combine them in a provider):

The constant definition:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .constant('AppConfiguration', { ... });
```

The service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('PiwikService', ['$window', 'AppConfiguration',
    function($window, AppConfiguration) {
      return {
        init: function() {
          $window._paq = $window._paq || [];

          var _paq = $window._paq;
          _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);

          var u = AppConfiguration.PiwikUrl;

          _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u + 'piwik.php']);
          _paq.push(['setSiteId', AppConfiguration.PiwikSiteId]);

          var g = angular.element('<script>')[0], 
              s = angular.element(document).find('script')[0];

          g.type = 'text/javascript';
          g.async = true;
          g.defer = true;
          g.src = u + 'piwik.js';
          s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s); 
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

You can then use this new service to initialize Piwik in a run block.

```
angular.module('myApp',[...])
  .run(['PiwikService',
    function(PiwikService) {
      PiwikService.init();
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: Hm, $document.createElement and $document.getElementsByTagName are not functions... We're getting closer though!

Comment: My fault, you should use the jQlite functions angular provides. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: We are down to the last line now :P
Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: You are the best!

Answer (score 0):

push your variable in `window` global object. like below and then access it like `window.objectname` in your piwik configuration script.

Add this code to add `appConfiguration` into window object.

```
window.appConfiguration = $rootScope.appConfiguration ;
```

then in your piwik configuration you can access it like

```
var _paq = _paq || [];
//_paq.push(['trackPageView']);
_paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
(function() {
    var u = window.appConfiguration.PiwikUrl;
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u + 'piwik.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', window.appConfiguration.PiwikSiteId]);
    var d = document, g = d.createElement('script'), s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type = 'text/javascript';
    g.async = true;
    g.defer = true;
    g.src = u + 'piwik.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
})();
```

### Update:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    // put your piwik code here
});
```

Comment: Where would you add the window.appConfiguration = $rootScope.appConfiguration ; snippet? In the .run of the module it doesn't seem to work (window.appConfiguration is undefined)

Comment: post your angular code where you are using `rootScope`

Comment: Ok, I will do it in the question :)

Comment: try doing like this `.run(function($rootScope) {
$rootScope.appConfiguration = appConfiguration;  window.appConfiguration = appConfiguration; 
});`

Comment: That doesn't work... By the way in angular you would use the $window service...but I tried that as well and it didn't change anything.

Comment: because your piwik code runs first before window object gets value. Try adding piwik code in angular ready function. Updating answer.

Comment: angular is not defined in there :p

Comment: You should know that for this you have to load angular before body tag.